# Handling large numbers

Tags: java, largenumber

I have this problem:

A positive integer is called a `palindrome` if its representation in the decimal system is the same when read from left to right and from right to left. For a given positive integer `K` of not more than `1000000` digits, write the value of the smallest palindrome larger than `K` to output. Numbers are always displayed without leading zeros.
Input

The first line contains integer `t`, the number of test cases. Integers `K` are given in the next `t` lines.
Output

For each `K`, output the smallest palindrome larger than `K`.
Example

Input:

```
2
808
2133
```

Output:

```
818
2222
```

My code converts the input to a string and evaluates either end of the string making adjustments accordingly and moves inwards. However, the problem requires that it can take values up to 10^6 digits long, if I try to parse large numbers I get a number format exception i.e.

```
Integer.parseInt(LARGENUMBER);
```

or

```
Long.parseInt(LARGENUMBER);
```

and `LARGENUMBER` is out of range. can anyone think of a work around or how to handle such large numbers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could probably use the [BigInteger](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) class to handle large integers like this.

However, I wouldn't count on it being efficient at such massive sizes. Because it still uses `O(n^2)` algorithms for multiplication and conversions.

Comment: BigInteger only handles numbers upto 20 digits long, does it not?

Comment: @Mead3000 BigInteger can (theoretically) handle numbers as large as your memory can handle.

Answer (score 5):

Think of your steps that you do now. Do you see something that seems a little superfluous since you're converting the number to a string to process it?

Comment: I dont know if you've heard of spoj.pl but the problem is from there... It runs fine on my computer but when I submit it to the site it exceeds the time limit. So I assume all the conversions give my algorithm a time complexity out of this world.
Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

While this problem talks about integers, its doing so only to restrict the input and output characters and format.  This is really a string operations question with careful selection.  Since this is the case, you really don't need to actually read the input in as integers, only strings.

This will make validating the palindrome simple.  The only thing you should need to work out is choosing the next higher one.

Comment: You could narrow the part of the string that needs to be modified by figuring out which parts are already a palindrome, eliminating those, taking the rest, converting it to a number, doing your arithmetic and then doing a string replace.  Maybe not.  Just a suggestion.

Comment: but when every digit needs changing, i.e 899999999 ---> 900000009 the value of the number as a whole need to be considered. Or am I missing a trick here